# Confusion in Builder plus Singleton pattern in example from fluffycat

Tags: java, design-patterns

I was tryingout builder examples from [fluffycat](http://www.fluffycat.com/Java-Design-Patterns/Bridge/)

```
SodaImpSingleton sodaImpSingleton = new SodaImpSingleton(new CherrySodaImp());
System.out.println("testing medium soda on the cherry platform");
MediumSoda mediumSoda = new MediumSoda();
mediumSoda.pourSoda();
```

here there is no relation between sodaImSingleton and mediumSuda, 
still when mediumSoda.pourSoda() is called it prints 
CherrySodaImp.pourSodaImp() how/why is this happening?

Comment: I recommend debugging the situation and just jumping into `pourSoda();` to see what's going on under the hood. Need to see more code to determine what's going on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a relationship. The `SodaImpSingleton` is instantiated with a `CherrySodaImp`. Next, `MediumSoda extends Soda` and in its constructor it is calling the method `setSodaImp()`, which is implemented as `SodaImpSingleton.getTheSodaImp();` in the abstract `Soda` class, a static method that returns the `CherrySodaImp` instance created on the first line.

Comment: public void setSodaImp() {
        this.sodaImp = SodaImpSingleton.getTheSodaImp();
  }

Answer (score 1):

`MediumSode.pourSoda()` calls `Soda.this.getSodaImp()` that returns `Soda.this.sodaImp` that is set by `MediumSoda()` constuctor via `Soda.this.setSodaImp()` to `static  SodaImpSingleton.getTheSodaImp()`. The value returned by `SodaImpSingleton.getTheSodaImp()` is set globally by calling `new SodaImpSingleton(new CherrySodaImp())`.

This example is so convoluted that I'd call it invalid.

Proper minimal singleton implementation would be:

```
public class Singleton {  
    private static Singleton instance;

    private Singleton () {
    }

    public static Singleton instance() {
        if(instance == null) {
            instance = new Singleton();
        }
        return instance;
    }
}
```

though it is not thead-safe.